# Is there any way to save it

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, lemons, greenhouse

Unfortunately it was placed in a greenhouse and then the vents closed for a full day or two leaving no ventilation

[image]

Comment: The tag says lemons. You don't say it's a lemon tree. Looks very dry. Spray with water?

Comment: It’s a variegated lemon tree.

Answer (score 1):

From the RHS website [here](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/types/trees/why-tree-shrub-died). How to tell if my tree or shrub is dead?

> 1. Scratch the bark (the “scratch test”) on the shoots of your trees or shrub with your thumb nail or a penknife. A stem with green under the bark is alive; a stem with brown under the bark is dead. Living shoots also tend to have smooth, firm bark, whereas dead or dying shoots tend to have flaking, peeling or wizened bark.
> 2. Where the shoots are dead at the tips, repeat the test on thicker wood to see if that is also dead. Where most or all of the upper parts of a plant are brown under the bark, the plant is most likely dead.
> 3. A final test is to scrape the bark of the main stem just below the soil line or on the roots themselves. If this appears dark in colour, especially with any sign of soft, rotting roots, then you can be confident your plant is dead.

Comment: From experience with peppers: if even the bottom 1cm shows signs of life: leaving it alone, watering it rarely and keeping it in the sun - sprouts in a week or two. But also do fight the root cause of the disaster.

Answer (score 0):

First drench it thoroughly.  Then water it for about 10 days and dont let it get too hot.  Either it will sprout some leaves or it wont.  To avoid this happening again,

**Use a self watering tray**

[image]

**Or use a spike with a coke bottle**

[image]

**Or use these watering stakes (they siphon water out of a reservoir)**

[image]

**Or use water storage crystals**

[image]

Comment: Watering really doesn't matter much in a greenhouse with the vents closed, so rather than linking a bunch of auto-watering devices, linking a bunch of **automatic vent openers** would address the actual problem better. It's been cooked. The soil could be completely saturated and it would still be cooked.